# How do I install live wallpapers I get from outside the android market? 

Tags: live-wallpaper

I have downloaded lots of Live wall papers from Android market.They work like charm.
I was trying to figure out a way to install Third party  live wall papers (Non-Android Market Specific) on my Samsung ACE 5830 Phone. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Check if on your phone you have the following option: `Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Unknown sources`.  Make sure it's checked to allow non-Market installs.

On older (and newer) Android OS versions this option could be under a different menu, or be absent altogether because some carriers disable this it.

Once the option is enabled and you have some Live Wallpapers downloaded from elsewhere, you should be able to side-load them.  Just copy the APK file to your SD Card, then use any one of the free [file browser apps](https://market.android.com/search?q=file+browser&c=apps&price=1) from Market to "launch" the APK from the SD Card.  This should invoke Android's built-in package installer and complete the installation.

Comment: IS there a way to move any other live wallpapers from my PC to the Samsung Phone

Comment: I'll edit my answer with instructions.